# Scroll bar doesn't stay within client area in Winforms tab control

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, scrollbar, tabcontrol

I have a `TabControl`, to which I am programmatically adding a `Form` with a `GridView` control on it to the Tab Controls `Controls` collection.  The result looks like this:

[image]

The GridView in the illustration actually has about 150 columns... When I use the horizontal scroll bar to scroll to the right, I get this:

[image]

Notice that the scroll-bar is not staying in the visible client area of the tab.  Instead, the scroll bar is assuming the width of the embedded form.

*How do I get the scroll bar to assume the width of the visible client area in the tab?*

Here is my code.  `PcmEditorForm` is just a blank form, with `FormBorderStyle` set to none, and there is some code that sets the number of rows and columns in the grid that's not shown here:

```
    private void LoadEditorTab()
    {
        var editor = new PcmEditorForm();
        var grid = new GridView();
        editor.Width = grid.Width;
        editor.Height = grid.Height;
        editor.Controls.Add(grid);
        editor.AutoScroll = true;
        editor.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top;
        tabEdit.Controls.Clear();
        editor.TopLevel = false;
        editor.Visible = true;
        tabEdit.Controls.Add(editor);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just dock the editor in the tabEdit.

```
private void LoadEditorTab()
    {
        var editor = new PcmEditorForm();
        var grid = new GridView();
        grid.width=editor.width
        grid.Anchor= AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right;
        editor.Controls.Add(grid);
        tabEdit.Controls.Clear();
        editor.TopLevel = false;
        editor.Visible = true;
        editor.dock=DockStyle.Fill;  // Dock the editor
        tabEdit.Controls.Add(editor);
    }
```

Comment: `Dockstyle.Fill` did the trick.  Anchor Styles don't seem to matter.